# Leverage of various option types

Tags: options, leverage

Does the standard European option calculation of leverage,

```
Embedded Leverage = Delta times (Underlying price/Option price)
```

change across the various option types? The types I'm most interested in are american, barrier, bermuda, quanto and cliquet. If the calculation is different what are the various formulas?

Comment: The definition of leverage ($\lambda$) is always the same, but of course the Delta and the Option Price depend on the particular option in question.(Barrier option for example is cheaper than Vanilla option, hence more leverage).

Comment: @AlexC I Understand prices and deltas may change however it seems odd that no adjustments to the standard formula are made, do you have a good reference or source for any of them?